# VMware: Mapping an NTFS drive without security permission restrictions

Tags: windows, vmware, ntfs, acl

I have a VMware image of a Windows machine.  I can map the drive.  *However*, when I do map it, I don't have permission to read everything on it.  (Host OS is Win 7 - I'm running as an Admin with LUA).

How can I map it so I have full read access? That is, map it (read only) so that my Windows gives me full permission to read everything.

Alternatively: Is there a command I can run that will copy and paste the contents, but change the owner to myself? Or a similar solution?

Answer (score 0):

Domain admin user on both the virtual PC and the physical PC should fix this.  The problem, i think, is that you physical box user doesn't get recognized as a priv user inside the mapped filesystem.

Comment: Right. But this shouldn't be necessary - I should be able to tell VMware to map the drive under my own user account.

Comment: it isn't about the mapping, it's about partition flags...do you want to rewrite the partition? i'll look into it if that's the case, otherwise best of luck